# Why is UART used over other interfaces for serial console?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, uart

In embedded systems, we often use UART to transmit data to a serial console on a PC, and these days with a USB-to-uart serial converter showing up as a virtual com port. Why has UART become the go-to for this instead of other serial interfaces like I2C and SPI?

Comment: Asynchronous serial communication as provided by a UART have been around since the original 75 baud mechanical teletype, i.e. years maybe decades longer than I2C and SPI. They are simple and very effective, only require a ground and rx+tx wires, and (as RS232 not logic level) can be used over relatively long distances.

Comment: @balmy Serial even employed terms like [space, mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#Voltage_levels) that originate in [early telegrpah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_space).  Serial goes back a long ways.

Answer (score 4):

Because is simple, was designed to be used on longer distances (I mean meters not kilometers :)), very standard and every uC has it.

I2C & SPI are not designed to be used outside the PCB (I know that people use them on longer distances). Those interfaces are used do connect other ICs to your microcontroller.

Comment: Because the OP asked about connections to a PC: Not to forget that PCs (or home computers or even simple terminals, and before the term "PC" meant "MS-DOS based x86" at all) used UARTs, but hardly other interfaces. And the protocol is so simple.

Comment: @thebusybee what I wrote : simple standard and designed for this purpose. I2C & SPI were not designed for this purpose

Comment: It’s not about distance, it’s about how easy to program it.

Comment: I2C is same easy to program - at least I do not have any problems with it. But it is not used

Comment: Not sure it’s easy enough. But of course there even more complex solutions are in the use, like USB DbC.

Comment: @0andriy It's definitely about distance. UART and SPI are both easy to use on the MCU side. They are both very old interfaces that were common in the 1980s and pre-date the first PC. The first PCs typically had RS-232 ports and parallel I/O ports but no SPI port - because it wouldn't make sense to connect PC devices over SPI due to distances and EMC. Also, programming UART communication on the PC side has never been trivial no matter OS.

Answer (score 1):

- Maximum distance of RS232 can be a few meter, I2C and SPI doesn't work well with distances longer than about 200 - 500mm (depending on pullups, speed, collector current, ...).
- SPI and I2C need a master and slave(s), there is no such difference between 2 UART hosts.
- You need fewer pins than SPI (when pins like DTR, DSR, RTS are omitted) or a parallel port.
- You don't need to worry about where to put a pullup-resistor.
- Both hosts can start a transmission asynchronous, with I2C and SPI the master needs to poll the slave before he can transmit data.
- A host doesn't need to answer immediately. This can be important on a PC under load where the reaction time can be very high (50ms or so). Try to write a program for a PC that can reliable answer in less than 1ms.

Comment: You forgot a very crucial detail, i.e. implementing UART in software is matter of ~3-5 LOCs either in C or assembler, which allows to debug on very early stages. What you are talking about is not so important.

Comment: @0andriy The 5 LOC implementation of a UART driver on bare metal is quite a challenge. Of course, something like reaction time is very important. Try to write a I2C slave on a PC that can be used to transmit arbitrary packets while the I2C bus works in 100 kHz without clock stretching.

Comment: It’s achievable, while for i2c is not so easy. Btw, USB has support of DbC, one may use that for (early) debugging,

Comment: @0andriy In a project with the PIC18F45K80, needed to init 6 UART registers, one of them twice, and that is just initialization. I don't see how a normal implementation could fit into 5 LOC without compromise readability.

Comment: "You don't need to worry about where to put a pullup-resistor." Well you do, you typically need one on the RX line to the MCU. Also RS-232 comes with a curse: Murphy's Law dictates that any UART implementation will _always_ mix up tx and rx. This happens in approximately 95-100% of all UART-based implementations I've ever seen.